# this net beans code gives " syntax error in insert into statement".. kindly tell me the right way

Tags: java, ms-access, netbeans-8

The following code used to run with another database with 4 variables. however, I am getting error this time..

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEventevt){                                         
    try
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con;

        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Database2");
        try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {

            String a=jTextField2.getText();

            String b=jTextField3.getText();
            String c=jTextField4.getText();
            String d=jTextField5.getText();

            String e=jTextField12.getText();
            String f= jTextField13.getText();
            String g = jTextField14.getText();

            int query;
            query =stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO ProductDatabase" + " (Id, Product, Price, Discount, Stock, Sold, Left)" + "VALUES('"+(a)+"','"+(b)+"','"+(c)+"','"+(d)+"','"+(e)+"','"+(f)+"','"+(g)+"')"); //insert query

            System.out.println("inserted");
        }
        con.close();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
    }       // TODO add your         // TODO add you
}
```

Comment: What's the error? What line? Obligatory "you should be using a parameterized query" suggestion.

Comment: `e.printStackTrace()` would be more useful than printing the message only...

Answer (score 1):

`LEFT` is [reserved word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738) in Access SQL, so you need to enclose that column name in square brackets:

```sql
INSERT ... Discount, Stock, Sold, [Left]) VALUES ( ...
```